# .forward file username and folder separator

Tags: postfix

I found (I'm learning how e-mail works) a `.forward` file in a user home folder; emails should be forwarded to mailboxes of other users. Email addresses are written in `user+folder` addressing notation, but instead of a `+` sign I found `-` sign; if I would like forward a spam message to Spam folder of a `user` I would write `user+Spam@domain.com`, but I found `user-Spam@domain.com`. The file contains email addresses in form:

This is an email server using Postfix.

```
user1-folder@domain.com` 
user2-folder@domain.com  
userN-folder@domain.com
```

Is there any difference?

Comment: You "found" it? _Where_? Is this on a mail server? On your personal computer? Can we see the actual file? Please [edit] your question and add more details, it is very hard to understand as it is.

Comment: Ok, I edited the message. Sorry for my poor english skills :/

Comment: Thanks for the edit, that's much clearer (and your English is fine, don't worry about it :) ). However, we still need to know what this machine is. It sounds like you are talking about a multi-user system that acts as a mailserver. Is that correct? If so, what mail server are you using? The details of this `.forward` file will probably depend on it. As far as I know, `.forward` is a `sendmail` feature, is that what you're using?

Comment: Yes, this is an e-mail server using Postfix.

Comment: Relevant: http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#recipient_delimiter

Comment: Yes, thank You. I was searching simultaneously I just found the recipient_delimiter too :) Thanks again.